# Rendering Web page urls in iframe by Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Javascript fragment

```
$("#testFrame iframe").attr("src", "debug.php?option=image");
```

displays in iframe the image when  is sent by the called debug.php program

With option=wikipedia

```
$("#testFrame iframe").attr("src", "debug.php?option=wikipedia");
```

Text "https://www.wikipedia.org"  is displayed in the iframe vs. content of that url.

How can url-s be rendered using similar Javascript technique?

PHP CODE:

';
    if ($option == 'wikipedia')     echo 'https://www.wikipedia.org'; 
?>

THANKS FOR THE HELP.

Comment: If you are wanting to get the source code of at a particular url within php you can use `file_get_contents('url')`, then just `echo` it

Comment: Thank you. How cam I display the contents into an iframe?

Comment: Is there a simple way to display a url via similar code in my example?

Comment: echo file_get_contents('https://www.wikipedia.org');

doesn't work with the above Javascript method

Comment: Sorry Patrick. It DOES work. Was just very slow for some reason.
THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Upon further testing with sample url's:  
a. with en.wikipedia.org got probably the full page, but the combined PHP & Javascript method reformatted the page

b. with www.cnn.com as test sample only part of the page was obtained/displayed

c. with file_get_contents("localhost:8090/html/1.html") got null string

Is there another way to do this?